# R parsing namespace for `match.fun()`

Tags: r, namespaces

In R, suppose I want to use `match.fun()` to call a function from a specific package, for example, `spam::eggs()`. If I do

```
library(spam)
sapply(1, FUN = match.fun("eggs"))
```

Then the function `spam::eggs()` will be invoked by `apply()`. But what if I do not want to attach the entire namespace? (I know I could also do `library(spam, include.only = "eggs")`, but suppose I don't want to attach anything to the namespace if I don't have to.)

```
match.fun("spam::eggs")
```

Will yield the error `"object 'spam::eggs' of mode 'function' was not found`. Is there an alternative to `match.fun()` that can parse what namespace to find the function in, using the `::` operator?

I'm aware that with `get()` you can find a function in a specific environment, but I'm not sure how to specify the environment to a package namespace that isn't attached already.

So is there any solution for this, or do I have to load the function into the global namespace for this to work?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I don't have the `fortunes` package attached in any way, but `match.fun(fortunes::fortune)` returns the code of that function, and `lapply(1, match.fun(fortunes::fortune))` returns the same as `fortunes::fortune(1)`.

Comment: Conversely, your code does not throw the errors you suggest... `apply` needs a `MARGIN` argument, and you seem to be mixing up `match.fun` (in your text) and `match.call` (in your code). Please check whether you do actually have a problem, and if so update your question to better reflect it.

Comment: `apply(matrix(1), FUN = match.fun(fortunes::fortune))` gives the error that "argument MARGIN is missing", but `apply(matrix(1), 1, FUN = match.fun(fortunes::fortune))` works just fine.

Comment: you're right, I should've used `sapply` as an example instead. The actual example I'm working on is a bit more complicated but I know that the `match.fun()` part is where the error is, so I made a mistake in trying to edit it down.

Comment: additionally, I forgot a lot of quotation marks in my question. If I had the raw names of the functions, I wouldn't need to use `match.fun()`, but instead I'm working with strings that represent function names.

Comment: This may be a case where `eval(parse())` makes sense. `sapply(1, FUN = eval(parse(text = "fortunes::fortune")))` works fine. If you want to be extra safe you could grep for `::` and if present use `eval(parse())` else use `match.fun()`.

Comment: I haven't seen `eval(parse())` before, but that seems to work, thank you! Is there any particular reason to prefer `match.fun()` over `eval(parse())` in the case where there's not a `::`?

Comment: `getFromNamespace()` might be useful here too, and safer than `eval(parse())`.

Comment: Don't use `eval(parse())`. You don't need it and it is bad practice. At least, it will make debugging your code a nightmare because you won't get useful error messages.

Comment: @Roland I'm all for avoiding `eval(parse())` generally, but I don't think it's bad here. `eval(parse(text = "spam::eggs"))` gives a perfectly sensible error message, `Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘spam’`. This seems like a fairly controlled environment, not a case where text strings are pasted together into code in a hard-to-trace way.